# Create custom autoid with date

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I want to generate autoid with date like date is 06 July 2013.
So the `id` should be `Q/XY/130701` which 13 means year, 07 means month, and 001 should be auto increment.

AutoID

Q/XY/130701

Q/XY/130702

Q/XY/130703

..
..

Q/XY/130710

Q/XY/1307100

Then if next month,the id will change to

Q/XY/130801

Q/XY/130802

and so on..
I want to create autoid once i enter 1 record into database and the autoid is generated and call out from database to display at GUI.
Any suggestion to do it? The database is sql server 2008.
Should i alter it like http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/491733/Auto-generated-sequence-number-in-SQL-Server?

Comment: please add any example of your question into your question .

Comment: What do you mean by "call out from database to display at GUI"?